# Insert range from existing rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have an existing table `SPLICE` in SQL Server 2008 that contains ranges of values:

```
+--------+----------+--------+--------------+
|OBJECTID|STARTRANGE|ENDRANGE|SOMEOTHERVALUE|
+--------+----------+--------+--------------+
|1       |2         |5       |ASDF          |
|2       |7         |7       |JKL           |
|3       |19        |20      |QWERTY        |
```

For each row in `SPLICE`, I want to insert into a new table `SPLICE_INDIVIDUAL` 1 row for each value between the STARTRANGE and ENDRANGE:

```
+--------+---+--------------+
|OBJECTID| V |SOMEOTHERVALUE|
+--------+---+--------------+
|1       |2  |ASDF          |
|1       |3  |ASDF          |
|1       |4  |ASDF          |
|1       |5  |ASDF          |
|2       |7  |JKL           |
|3       |19 |QWERTY        |
|3       |20 |QWERTY        |
```

What's the best (fastest and most readable) way to do this?

Comment: If you have some sort of numbers table (e.g. numbers up to a million, indexed), joining that would probably be the most efficient way. If you don't have one, I'd recommend creating one anyway - you can google how if you're unsure of what you'd need to do. Failing that, if you have an idea of the range of numbers you're looking at, you can just use `FROM(VALUES(...))` or a CTE to produce numbers on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where a good Tally function really helps...

Here is the code for one I created a little while back.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tfn_Tally
/* ============================================================================
07/20/2017 JL, Created. Capable of creating a sequense of rows 
                ranging from -10,000,000,000,000,000 to 10,000,000,000,000,000
============================================================================ */
(
    @NumOfRows BIGINT,
    @StartWith BIGINT 
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
RETURN
    WITH 
        cte_n1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (n)),   -- 10 rows
        cte_n2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n1 a CROSS JOIN cte_n1 b),                             -- 100 rows
        cte_n3 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n2 a CROSS JOIN cte_n2 b),                             -- 10,000 rows
        cte_n4 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n3 a CROSS JOIN cte_n3 b),                             -- 100,000,000 rows
        cte_Tally (n) AS (
            SELECT TOP (@NumOfRows)
                (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1) + @StartWith
            FROM 
                cte_n4 a CROSS JOIN cte_n4 b                                                    -- 10,000,000,000,000,000 rows
            )
    SELECT 
        t.n
    FROM 
        cte_Tally t;
GO
```

And here it is in use...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SPLICE', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #SPLICE;

CREATE TABLE #SPLICE (
    OBJECTID INT NOT NULL,
    STARTRANGE INT NOT NULL,
    ENDRANGE INT NOT NULL,
    SOMEOTHERVALUE VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #SPLICE (OBJECTID, STARTRANGE, ENDRANGE, SOMEOTHERVALUE) VALUES
    (1, 2 , 5 , 'ASDF'),
    (2, 7 , 7 , 'JKL'),  
    (3, 19, 20, 'QWERTY');

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SPLICE_INDIVIDUAL', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #SPLICE_INDIVIDUAL;

CREATE TABLE #SPLICE_INDIVIDUAL (
    OBJECTID INT NOT NULL,
    V INT NOT NULL,
    SOMEOTHERVALUE VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #SPLICE_INDIVIDUAL (OBJECTID, V, SOMEOTHERVALUE)
SELECT 
    s.OBJECTID,
    t.n,
    s.SOMEOTHERVALUE
FROM
    #SPLICE s
    CROSS APPLY dbo.tfn_Tally(s.ENDRANGE - s.STARTRANGE + 1, s.STARTRANGE) t;

SELECT * FROM #SPLICE_INDIVIDUAL si;
```

And the data inserted into SPLICE_INDIVIDUAL...

```
OBJECTID    V           SOMEOTHERVALUE
----------- ----------- --------------
1           2           ASDF
1           3           ASDF
1           4           ASDF
1           5           ASDF
2           7           JKL
3           19          QWERTY
3           20          QWERTY
```

Comment: How much slower is that function with the last cte? I noticed a big lag a while back. UV from me too

Comment: It's fast... It'll pump 1M rows into a temp table in ~ 400 milliseconds... and that's on a woefully under resourced dev machine.
Try it. I think you'll like it. :)

Comment: I definitely plan to tomorrow !

Answer (score 1):

**Test Data**

```
Declare @t TABLE (OBJECTID INT , STARTRANGE INT 
                                 , ENDRANGE INT , SOMEOTHERVALUE VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
(1   ,2       ,5      ,'ASDF'   ),
(2   ,7       ,7      ,'JKL'    ),
(3   ,19      ,20     ,'QWERTY' )
```

**Query**

```
SELECT t.OBJECTID
     , t.STARTRANGE + c.Number AS V
     , t.SOMEOTHERVALUE
FROM @t t
  CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT TOP ((t.ENDRANGE + 1) - t.STARTRANGE) 
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 Number
                FROM master..spt_values x CROSS JOIN master..spt_values y
              ) c
```

**Result Set**

```
╔══════════╦════╦════════════════╗
║ OBJECTID ║ V  ║ SOMEOTHERVALUE ║
╠══════════╬════╬════════════════╣
║        1 ║  2 ║ ASDF           ║
║        1 ║  3 ║ ASDF           ║
║        1 ║  4 ║ ASDF           ║
║        1 ║  5 ║ ASDF           ║
║        2 ║  7 ║ JKL            ║
║        3 ║ 19 ║ QWERTY         ║
║        3 ║ 20 ║ QWERTY         ║
╚══════════╩════╩════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use another table (called a Tally table) which contains a list of numbers 1...

You then join this tally table to your table in order to generate the additional rows

for example

select *
  from tally as t
  join splice as s on t.number between s.startrange and s.endrange